# Aligning a model on a wall

Tags: rotation, arcore

I have a hitResult relative to a detected plane:

```
arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(
    (HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) -> {...})
```

I want to anchor a model to the plane and have it always face up (the ceiling):

```
Anchor anchor = plane.createAnchor(plane.getCenterPose());
AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
anchorNode.setRenderable(model);
```

The problem is that the model is sometimes randomly rotated. Sometimes, it does not point the ceiling: it is rotated 180 degrees, 90 degrees, or random.

(At least, all this in the emulator).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
boolean isVerticalPlane = plane.getType() == Plane.Type.VERTICAL;
```

inside your `setOnTapArPlaneListener` from your `ArFragment`.

Final code will be:

```
ArFragment arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment);

arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(new BaseArFragment.OnTapArPlaneListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTapPlane(HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                boolean isVerticalPlane = plane.getType() == Plane.Type.VERTICAL;
            }
        });
```